# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'cavnus'@'localhost' to database 'vishipel'

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jax-rs, connector-j

I'm developing a JAX-RS service which run on Tomcat 8.0, and I got an exception when try to access Mysql database on my server. Here is exception which I got :

```
    13-Jul-2018 11:36:30.899 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2752 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:31.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
13-Jul-2018 11:36:31.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
13-Jul-2018 11:36:31.102 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\Vishipel.war
13-Jul-2018 11:36:42.102 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'cavnus'@'localhost' to database 'vishipel'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:728)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:662)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:559)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:847)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:835)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:565)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:973)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

13-Jul-2018 11:36:42.117 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'cavnus'@'localhost' to database 'vishipel'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:728)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:662)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:559)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:847)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:835)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:565)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:973)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

13-Jul-2018 11:36:42.133 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource Failed to register in JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'cavnus'@'localhost' to database 'vishipel']]
13-Jul-2018 11:36:42.258 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:42.617 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [234] milliseconds.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:42.852 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.vishipel
13-Jul-2018 11:36:43.336 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class com.vishipel.service.UsersService
  class com.vishipel.service.NewsService
  class com.vishipel.service.CustomerService
  class com.vishipel.service.PostageService
13-Jul-2018 11:36:43.336 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:43.961 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM'
13-Jul-2018 11:36:49.055 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\Vishipel.war has finished in 17,953 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:49.055 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs
13-Jul-2018 11:36:49.899 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:49.899 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs has finished in 844 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:49.899 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\examples
13-Jul-2018 11:36:51.195 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:51.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\examples has finished in 1,515 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:51.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\host-manager
13-Jul-2018 11:36:53.836 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:53.836 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\host-manager has finished in 2,422 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:53.836 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager
13-Jul-2018 11:36:54.695 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:54.695 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 859 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:54.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT
13-Jul-2018 11:36:55.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Jul-2018 11:36:55.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 1,000 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:55.758 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 24854 ms
13-Jul-2018 11:36:55.758 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
```

Here is my code :
context.xml to config Mysql connection

```
<Context>
    <Resource name = "jdbc/vishipel"
    auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="25" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
        maxTotal="50" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" 
        defaultAutoCommit="true"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        username="cavnus" password="cavnus2016#"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vishipel"/>
</Context>
```

Define resource-ref in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/vishipel</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And here is code which I use to initialize DataSource

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Database {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Database.class);
    private static DataSource ds = null;

    static {
        logger.info("Inside Database() static method...");
        Context context = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/vishipel");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            logger.error("Unable to get DataSource..." + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource(){
        return ds;
    }

}
```

It's work as well on my local with this code. But I got this exception when deploy to Tomcat on my server with war file which exported from my project.

My server is running Window Server 2012 R2 Standard 64 bit and MySql running on Wamp Server.

I'm already copy mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar into lib folder of Tomcat or set it to classpath enviroment. But I still got exceptions

Someone kindly help and give me a solution for this problem.

Thank you so much !

Comment: What does it say if you open a mysql console and type ```SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;``` and ```SHOW GRANTS FOR 'YOUR_USER'@'YOUR_HOST';```. The error would imply that either the user does not exist or the host is wrong or you don't have permissions set for the User.

Comment: I have 4 user in mysql.user
`cavnus %
cavnus localhost
mysql.sys localhost
root localhost`

and here is result when call `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'cavnus'@'localhost';`
**GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'cavnus'@'localhost'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `cavnus`.* TO 'cavnus'@'localhost'**

Comment: And I can use this my **cavnus** account and its password to remote access to my database via MySQLWorkbench

Comment: Try percent encoding hash sign in the password `cavnus2016%23`, it's a reserved character for MySQL connection URL.

Comment: I changed password to `cavnus2016%23` but I got same error `SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'cavnus'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:127)`
And `WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'cavnus'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: I still got Warning for FAIL to register resource `WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource Failed to register in JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'cavnus'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]]`. I think it relate to context.xml file not be registered

Comment: check server.xml and other context files for duplicated configuration. Sometimes when developing we try things and then forget about them.

Comment: My project is Maven project, the configuration of database conenction just set in context.xml file as above, and this resource be defined in web.xml as I post, Luis